# Control upload file size using web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I need to control upload max file size per folder in my asp.net mvc app. So I have in root web.config

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024" />
</system.web>
```

and then I have upload folder structure as such
Uploads-
        User1
        User2
So I added web.config for user 1 folder where I set maxRequestLength to 20480. But it does not effect my app. It looks like my overrides not effect my app.
Any suggestions???

Answer (score 1):

in the root web.config, add `Location` tags for each sub folder like this:

```
<location path="Uploads/User1">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" />
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Uploads/User2">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```